# Serialize array of objects as one object with a named property for each object in C# with JSON serializer

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, object

I have a List that, when serialized as JSON gives me an array of objects. However, I need the serialized version to be structured as follows:

```
{
  "item3":{
    "id":3,
    "name":"monkey"
  },
  "item4":{
    "id":4,
    "name":"turtle"
  }
}
```

Currently, the JSON serialization is structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"monkey"
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "name":"turtle"
  }
]
```

My goal is to be able to reference the array by item ID instead of numeric index (ie. arr["item3"].name instead of arr[0].name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might did that just putting the data into a dictionary is enough for JaveScripySerializer:

```
var dict = list.ToDictionary(
    item => "item" + item.id);
```

(and serialize dict)

If not:

I don't have a PC handy for an example, but you should be able to:

- write a wrapper class that encapsulated the list/array
- use the JavaScriptSerializer class
- after creating the serializer, associate the wrapper-type with a custom serializer
- in the custom serializer, iterate over the data, adding a key to the dictionary per-item, i.e. data.Add("item"+i,list[i]);

You associate custom maps via RegisterConverters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx

Note you don't need to write a deserialize unless you need that too.

If you get stuck, I'll try to ad an example later.

Comment: I think this will work just fine. Thank you for the prompt response :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for that... I'll give that a shot before diving into the RegisterConverters business. Thanks Marc